# How to convert data read from data reader to base64 string and add to datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable

i have binary data stored (data of an image) stored in the database. So basically i want to retrieve that data , convert it into base 64 string and put it into a data table as i will be returning the datatable into a webservice.

The code for retrieving the data from the database is as follows.

```
public DataTable GetImageDetails(string userName)
{
    DataTable imageTable = new DataTable();
    imageTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("img_storage", typeof(String)));


    if (dbConnection.State.ToString() == "Closed")
    {
        dbConnection.Open();
    }

    string query = "SELECT img_storage FROM Image_table WHERE vehicle_no IN( SELECT vehicle_no FROM User_table  WHERE username='" + userName + "')";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, dbConnection);

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            imageTable.Rows.Add(reader["img_storage"]);
        }
    }

    reader.Close();
    dbConnection.Close();
    return imageTable;
}
```

How can I convert data and add to the data table by editing this code? Please Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])` on the data returned from the DataReader (which you'll need to cast as a `byte[]`).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir!! But i'm confused on how to do the above mentioned Convert.ToBase64String(byte[]) . I refered the link, but still no luck. Can you be kind enough to provide me the code line with respect to my code. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user2766227 imageTable.Rows.Add(Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])reader["img_storage"]));

Comment: Sir thankyou again for your answer. I have a small question. Will this convert the data returned by the reader and put it into the column "img_storage" in data table which is image_table

Comment: @user2766227 Yes, you have defined your DataTable with a single column with that name and are adding a single-value row to that DataTable with the encoded value.